# find any summary that does not end with a dot

Tags: regex, visual-studio, summary

I am looking for consistency in my projects. But I don't always remember that it when I am typing. This leads me to an issue when I have commented half of my project and I don't know if I ended all the lines with a .

So, I'd like to find all the summaries that does not end with a dot to remedy this. An example of this is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is my summary
    /// </summary>
```

This means that there is starting white spaces, always three `/` and they are all enclosed within a `<summary>` tag.

I started working on it and got this:

```
^///$[^\.]
```

based on

```
^ start of line
/// the three slashes
$ end of line
[^\.] that doesn't end with a dot.
```

But I fail to get it to work.
How do I find all the summary lines that does not end with a .?

Comment: `.` does not need to be escaped when it is inside a character class (`[]`). For instance, `[a.]` matches only the `a` or `.` characters, not any character.

Comment: I added the visual studio. Whenever you do regexen, specifying the flavour is essential (there are several dialects that subtly differ)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to anchor to the start of the string, as it is the '///' that marks the the start of a comment line

```
///.*[^\.]$
```

how we build this up.

we know that the comments we are looking for start with '///' and end with not '.', those two strings can be matched as '///' and '[^.]' in between we can have anything, so '.*'

You do not need a '^' at the start, as a comment does not have to start at the start of the string/line.

You might also want to account for trailing white space, so

```
///.*[^\.]\s*$
```

I might have missed a few other points, so just shout up

**what does `$` mean**

The '$' symbol in regex is an anchor for the end of the string. It sort of matches new lines, except (perhaps depending on implementation) it can match simply the end of input. It works the same as '^' which matches the start of input

Comment: here we go! this one fixed it. Would you mind explaining the process?

Comment: Ok, the final question is what the $ takes for input (all though I'm fairly certain that I understand it). Does it work just like * as to "take the last character as input"?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to account for whitespace between the real start of the line (col 0) and the `///`. Maybe this will work `^\s*///.*[^.]$`.

- `^` - start of line (which is column 0, not the first visible character)
- `\s*` - optional whitespace
- `///` - start of comment
- `.*` - any text
- `[^.]` - anything but a `.`
- `$` - end of line (which is after the last character)

**EDIT**
The Visual Studio search-regex apparently differs from regular regexes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

It seems like you need a `:Zs` instead of a `\s` to match whitespace (or skip that entirely and use just `///.*[^.]$`, as suggested).

Comment: Which is weird. Should this match all lines that start with "whitespace + ///"?

Comment: This ( ^\s*/// ) simply matches all lines that start with some (or none) white space and then three slashes

Comment: Visual Studio states that it cannot find this text. Could it be VS that does not understand /s?

Comment: @Default - I changed the partial regex to the full one and added an explanation.

Comment: There is no need to relate this to the start of a string, thus there is no need for the '^\s*' at the start of the match

Comment: @HansKesting thanks. Although I think VS has some issues with `\s`. Even doing a search for `\s` matches `S` or `s`, not whitespace

Comment: Although it did not work I upvoted this. (I guess it **should** work..)

Comment: @Default perhaps the VS regex engine requires that `[^.]` escape the '.' You also do not need the leading '^\s*' in this pattern

Comment: @jersten - a `.` inside `[ ]` *is* a literal dot, not a wildcard. So you don't need to escape it (unlike the `.*` where it *is* a wildcard).